# SQL Type NOW() not working

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have this query;

```
"INSERT INTO download(download_key, ip, file, expire) VALUES ('".$text."', 
'".$mysql->real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."', 
'".$searchQuery['file_match']."', 
'NOW() + INTERVAL 10 MINUTES')"
```

When I insert this in the database, the row expire is always 0000-00-00 00:00:00. I have tried the types:

- TIMESTAMP
- DATE
- DATETIME
- TIME

But is always 0000-00-00 00:00:00 or 00:00:00.

What is the right type for NOW()? I`m using MYSQL

Comment: Note that it's better to avoid concatenating strings altogether in favor of prepared statements - otherwise you run the risk of SQL Injection (for instance, are you **absolutely** sure that `$text` and `$searchQuery['file_match']` are safe?).  Please read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for some more info (which states that `$mysql->real_escape_string() is deprecated, too).

Comment: Yes, $text is random, no user input. $searchQuery['file_match'] is comming out of the database.

Comment: _How_ was `$searchQuery['file_match']` put into the database?  ie, does someone have the ability to add random text to the file?  Such as a SQL query string?  It's best to assume that all text is suspect (Especially from a dynamic source), and to use prepared statements.  You don't need a dynamic query (concatenated string) here.  There is a use case for dynamic statements, but those are usually small, and the 'attack surface' can be limited even then.  For instance, don't concatenate dynamic queries with their parameters - prepare the (new) statement as normal.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the quotes,quotes are for strings

```
NOW() + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```

Comment: Still 0000-00-00 00:00:00
type: DATETIME

Comment: +1 this. I'm gonna add one more thing - quotes are not a mistake for type date, but you need to put the date in correct syntax if you are passing a string for date, so for example generate correct date in PHP or whatever language you are using. So correct SQL would be also: `"', '2013-11-24 12:00:00')"`

Comment: Are you sure anything is getting inserted?Check if you have the last row.

Answer (score 1):

```
"INSERT INTO download(download_key, ip, file, expire) VALUES ('".$text."', 
'".$mysql->real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."', 
'".$searchQuery['file_match']."', 
NOW() + INTERVAL 10 MINUTES)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna add a little thing to people already said.

Except the thing you shouldn't pass sql functions as string so don't put `NOW() + INTERVAL 10 MINUTES` in quotes, you can pass a string for date also. You can generate this date with php for example.

Try this fiddle to check how to put simple DATE in database: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cddc1/1

Also with PHP you can generate the date with this code:

```
$minutes = 10;
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() + $minutes*60);
$query = "INSERT INTO download(download_key, ip, file, expire) VALUES ('$text', 
'{$mysql->real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])}', 
'{$searchQuery['file_match']}', 
'$date')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Kelu Thatsall:
Fix:

```
NOW() + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```